# Ajax SQL Populate select dropdown based on input

Tags: php, ajax

I have an input(typeahead) where users are supposed to type in a name. Based on that name, I am using ajax to retrieve two different set of values from the database that I display in 2 dropdowns. These two fields are arrival type and sub-name.

I have added an onchange action on the input and calling the function when the user starts typing.

It does not seem to work so far. Here is my code

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead text_field"  
   name="name_alias" id="name_alias" placeholder="Search unit" style="min- 
    width:200px;"  onChange="getNameType();" required/>


function getNameType()
{
    if (ajax) {
        var name_alias = document.getElementById("name_alias").value;

        if(name_alias) {
            var param = "?name_alias=" + name_alias;
            var url = "getNameType.php";
            ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax3;
            ajax.send(null);
        }
    }
}

function handleAjax3()                                                                                                                           
{
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        var arrival_type = document.getElementById('arrival_type');
        if(!!ajax.responseText) {
            var result = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            if(!!result){
                $('#arrival_type').val((!!result.arrival_type) ? result.arrival_type: '');
            } 
        }
    }
 }
```

My getNameType File

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$name_alias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['name_alias']);
$query = "SELECT arrival_type 
          FROM table_namer 
          WHERE name_alias='".$name_alias."' 
          LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$response = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $response['arrival_type'] = ($row['arrival_type'] != '') ? $row['arrival_type'] : '';

    }
}
echo  json_encode($response, true); 
?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: What is not working ? Do you see the request and the response with the developer console ?

Comment: If you have a `LIMIT 1` on the query, then what is the point of a WHILE loop to process the resultset??

Comment: There is not much point in this line either `($row['arrival_type'] != '') ? $row['arrival_type'] : ''` if you think about it !:)

Comment: And you are definitely MIXING UP raw js AJAX and jQuery AJAX and getting in a right mess in the process

Comment: So, to sum up @RiggsFolly ... this code needs a total redo :)

Comment: Nicely put @IncredibleHat

Comment: Thanks, I will re-write my code. Can you please remove the negative as I don;t think I deserved it. I am still learning like everybody else.